# Search a Batch of Files for a Line of Text

Tags: search, mercurial, repository

I have a Mercurial Repository for a code project and I want to search all of the files, in all directories and sub-directories, for a given string. What is the best method, or program to do so?

I can conduct this search in Ubuntu Linux or a Windows environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to just do a checkout of the repository and use [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin) on windows, or grep on Linux.

Comment: You have a good example of that for Linux? The string I wish to search for is something along the lines of abUser, and the case is the same everywhere (or the code wouldn't work). Probably a stupid question, but I can't get my mind around it this morning :-\

Comment: BAM. Once I have my coffee I am no longer stupid. No need for a program >< user:~$ grep -r -i abUser /home/user/Mercurial/workRepos/myTool/default-Branch/ > myGrep.txt

Comment: +1 for the grepWin app though, I am going to keep that for later on down the road.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple search in the working copy, I would also use the normal `grep` program (I'm on Linux).

But if you want to search the history for a string, then note that Mercurial also has a `hg grep` function. That can be handy if you want to see when a given function, say, was introduced or removed.

Answer (score 0):

If TortoiseHg is installed **Search History** is available in Windows Explorer context menu.